# How to add a list of Predicates to CriteriaBuilder.or

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria, predicate

I have a List to append in an or condition

The Issue I am facing is when I am iterating over the List and adding it to the CategoryBuilder then it takes the last Predicate

Following is the example:

```
public static Specification<Billoflading> hasTenantAndBillingCodeCombination(List<WhoOwnsIt> list,
            Date formattedFromDate, Date formattedToDate, String carrierFilter, String supplierFilter,
            String terminalFilter) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

            for (WhoOwnsIt whoOwnsIt : list) {
                String containsLikePatternForTenant = getContainsLikePattern(whoOwnsIt.getWholesalerTenantID(), true);

                Predicate pred = cb.and(cb.like(cb.lower(root.<String>get("tenant")), containsLikePatternForTenant),
                        cb.equal(cb.lower(root.<String>get("billingCode")), whoOwnsIt.getBillingCode()),
                        cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.<Date>get("scheduleDate"), formattedFromDate),
                        cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.<Date>get("scheduleDate"), formattedToDate));

                Predicate predWithTenant = null;

                if (null != carrierFilter) {
                    predWithTenant = cb.and(cb.equal(cb.lower(root.<String>get("tenant")), carrierFilter));
                }

                if (null != predWithTenant)
                    predicates.add(predWithTenant);
                else
                    predicates.add(pred);

            }
            Predicate finalPredicate;
            // This commented section below needs to be replaced with a 
            //better solution
            //for(Predicate predicate : predicates){
            //  cb.or(predicate);
            //}

            return finalPredicate;
        };
    }
```

I also tried making the List an array for passing it to the finalPredicate.or as follows

```
Predicate finalQuery = cb.or(predicates.toArray());
```

But this code gave compilation error as the parameters needed is varargs
i.e.

or method accepts (Predicate... predicates) as parameter list

Can you please provide some simple solution to this issue?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this:

```
Predicate finalQuery = cb.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
```

Comment: Thanks, for the quick response, this solution works but with slight edit,

i.e. new Predicate[length]
where length is the No. Of elements that needs to fit in

It was so close, great catch!!

Comment: No problem. We use it everywhere in the code with a length of 0, but ok

Comment: The Change was a small one as follows

Predicate finalQuery = cb.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));

Comment: Ohh okay the 0 length might also be working, I will try that, but first time it gave me some exception might be due to some outofbounds exception, in java version 1.8.151

Comment: Thank you very much @nicoschi this saved my day, its a great and simple solution which I missed!!

Answer (score 8):

As an addition I would suggest using the following notation for newer Java versions:

```
builder.or(predicates.toArray(Predicate[]::new))
```

Answer (score 2):

A sample code I wrote that might be helpful, here am gathering all predicates in a list and then converted list to array which is getting consumed by builder.

```
 public List< EntityClass> getData(List<Long> ids) {

    List<List<Long>> idPartitions = ListUtils.partition(ids, 999);
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<EntityClass> criteria = builder.createQuery(EntityClass.class);

    Root<EntityClass> root = criteria.from(EntityClass.class);

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>(idPartitions.size());
    for (List<Long> idPartition : idPartitions) {
      predicates.add(root.get("id").in(idPartition));
    }

    criteria.where(builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
    List<EntityClass> objects = entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
    return objects;
  }
```